# Blender runs really slowly on my Cintiq 22HD

Tags: performance

I have a computer with a three monitor setup.  One of the monitors is a Cintiq 22HD that allows me to draw on the screen.  I also have an old Intuos 3 hooked up that lets me draw with a pen in the older 'blind' way.

When I start blender and have it displaying on my main monitor, I can draw with my Intuos and Blender is very responsive.  However, if I drag my Blender application over to display on my Cintiq and try to draw with the Cintiq stylus, the response time is so slow I cannot effectively use it.  I would like to be able to use Blender on my Cintiq so I can see the graphics under my pen.  Perhaps for some reason the Cintiq is not using my graphics card to accelerate OpenGL?

Anyone know how to get Blender to run at a useful speed on a Cintiq 22HD?

Comment: My feeeling is that your graphics card is not powerful enough to deal with three monitors and blender. Try disabling two of the monitors and using the cintiq as the only monitor and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know more about your machine: what processor, what speed, how much memory, what video cards what OS. Also, make sure you have the latest drivers updated, and that there are no other issues with your computer. I had a much less sophisticated installation of Blender that started running slow, and it turned out to be malware in the system..

Comment: I have an Intel Xeon quadcore CPU that runs at 3GHz.  I have 8GB RAM and two NVidia Quadro K600 installed.  The OS is Windows 7.  I scan my computer regularly and am pretty sure there's no malware or viruses.  The Cintiq driver is updated to the latest version.  In any case, Blender runs fast enough on my other monitors - it's just the Cintiq that is slow.

Comment: Try full-screening Blender (Alt-F11), it might help.

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't help.